# Maximum calldata size per block

Tags: calldata, ethjs

I'm trying to use calldata to store data.  It works fine with some smaller datasets (50kb), but for some reason when I try store ~150kb I get the following error

> code
> :
> -32603
> message
> :
> "[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32000,"message":"oversized data"}}'"

The maximum gas per block is 30M and I'm trying to create a transaction that is 2.5M.  Why can't I create this transaction??

Edit: Is there a maximum size limit on items in a bytes[]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com)

From a web3 infrastructure provider's point of view, you are really pushing our limit here.

This error comes from your RPC provider, your request data exceed the maximum tx data that is allowed, which is 128KB. It is set in Geth's [txpool](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/txpool/txpool.go) implementation:

The code:

```
    // txMaxSize is the maximum size a single transaction can have. This field has
    // non-trivial consequences: larger transactions are significantly harder and
    // more expensive to propagate; larger transactions also take more resources
    // to validate whether they fit into the pool or not.
    txMaxSize = 4 * txSlotSize // 128KB
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So what are my options here?  Do i need to split the data into two separate transactions?  Since this is a Geth config, I assume that if i spin up my own node and send the transaction, it wont be propagated to the majority of nodes.  How do l2's do this? Do they just keep their total tx size below 128kb?

Comment: I see a discussion between Geth team and a L2 provider in this GH issue page:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/23920

Based on the discussion, it seems like there is no workaround for now. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will mark this as the answer.